# How to get .NET CORE version number of target system in C#

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I want to deploy my application in a system before deploying i need to check what version of .NET core framework is running, if its less then 3.1 then install 3.1 in that server if its already 3.1 or greater then install my application.

Comment: what do you mean by if .net version is already 3.1 or greater then install my application? For how to check running .Net core version, I have posted my answer below!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see which *.Net core* version is running by typing following command on command prompt:

`dotnet --version`

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on your project name, select `Properties`, and you can directly see the version of your current project in the first `Application` option by default in the displayed window.

[image]
[image: f]